# How to convert array php with an object json

Tags: arrays, json, object

I have one array with PHP like this:

```
Array (
      [SCAN] => Array (
                      [SITE] => Array ([0] => http://www.site.com ) 
                      [DOMAIN] => Array ([0] => www.site.com )
                      [IP] => Array ( [0] => 134.0.xx.xxx )
                      )
      [SYSTEM] => Array ( [NOTICE] )
      )
```

And I need to convert an object JSON with json_encode() function. But the problem is returns me this:

```
"Array\n(\n[SCAN] => Array\n (\n [SITE] => Array\n (\n [0] => http:\/\/www.site.com \n)\n\n"
```

Comment: Can you show actual code?

Comment: Looks like you are encoding some kind of string representation of the array, not the array itself.